# Resource handler in quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I need a resource handler to serve static resources. I know that to serve static resources I should place them in `META-INF/resources`. I want to add resource handler with URL path patterns and configure the locations to serve static resources.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into Quarkus' [Reactive Routes](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes).
They essentially allow you to register a [Vert.x Route](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_basic_vert_x_web_concepts) in a more declarative way.
In the implementation of your Route, you can do whatever you like.
For reference, [this](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/blob/4.1.1/vertx-web/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/web/handler/impl/StaticHandlerImpl.java) is how Vert.x's serves static resources.

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68347961/8284722, a solution can be:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class StaticContentDeclarativeRoute {

    @Route(path = "/static/*", methods = Route.HttpMethod.GET)
    void staticContent(RoutingContext rc) {
        StaticHandler.create(FileSystemAccess.RELATIVE, "content/").handle(rc);
    }

}
```

and consider the path can also be absolute using `FileSystemAccess.ROOT`